# Xwiki comparison version

Tags: xwiki

I tried but it is showing for code level I want from content level like suppose we have created page and have done some modification then if we see the history then version will be created and I am comparing the two version then it should show from content level why it is showing from code level.

Answer (score 0):

XWiki pages use wiki syntax as their content. Depending on what you write in your page, you could use more or you could use less wiki syntax in your content (e.g. like writing more plain text vs adding a lot of styling like bolds, lists, images, macros, etc.), so your page content could look more like a page of a book with a lot of phrases and paragraphs, or it could be a mix of textual content and code or stylized content. When you view a page, all that content (wiki syntax) is interpreted and rendered into HTML that your web browser displays to you as lists, images, etc. (and not raw textual wiki syntax).

When comparing 2 XWiki page versions, as also mentioned in the user documentation page about this topic https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/VersionControl, you will see the differences between the content of the page between the 2 compared versions. Since the content inside the wiki pages is actually text (plain text + a bit more or a bit less wiki syntax), the diff that you will see will also be text based.

The same thing happens when you would want to compare 2 versions of a webpage, not related to XWiki. If you want to see *only* the changes, it is not technically possible to show it in a user-friendly manner (similar to the rendering that is done in view mode), so you will be presented with the blocks of textual differences (in this case, HTML code and plain text) between the 2 versions.

The only case where something "visual" could be presented, would be if the 2 versions were displayed individually and completely, side by side to one-another, so that you could visually scan and detect the differences. However, if you would not be able to spot the differences yourself, or if the differences were not visual, but only at a syntax (code) level, this kind of comparison view would not be very useful to a user. Also, if the is huge, it would quickly become a pain to visually scan the differences between the 2 renderings of the 2 versions.

The problem lies in your definition of "content" because the "content" is, as explained above, actually the "code" (wiki syntax, to be more precise). It's like comparing 2 pages of a book and showing only the blocks that differ: they will contain text, not the pieces of paper that text is written on :) (a bit of a long shot analogy, I know :) ).

To make it easier to understand, try creating a wiki page full with only text (like 2-3 paragraphs), make a couple of changes and then look at the history between some versions. Does that look "better" and more like "content" to you?

Hope this helps.